# No internet using Intel Wireless-AC 9462 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

Hi I am trying to set up a new laptop with Ubuntu. For some reason my wifi card doesn't seem to be working. I can connect to the desired access point but I can only get the internet working with a cable, not the wifi. The driver seems to be installed and running but additional drivers is showing the device is not working:
[image]
Here is a dmesg indicating the issue might be firmware?
[image]
I was able to find the official firmware for my card from Intel [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) and tried adding the file to my /lib/firmware folder like the instructions say but that didn't seem to help...

Anyone see the issue?

Adding more requested info:
[image]
I do seem to be connected to my desired access point "Wirefly"
[image]
[image]
^ There were a couple more changed bandwith messages I couldn't fit in this pic but they were pretty much all the same as the shown ones.

dmesg after changing iwlwifi 11n_disable=8:
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: ...I thought I did? Nothing what show but those 7 lines

Comment: With the ethernet disconnected, please run and post: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and also: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` and finally: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` It wasn't clear that your dmesg was the entirety of messages related to iwl, only firmware. Sorry.

Comment: Are you quite certain that you are actually connected? `sudo nmcli dev status` and also: `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: yeah, needed my password and everything. I am not going to show all my neighbors SSIDs but here is the top part of that last command showing my desired AP "Wirefly" being used as denoted by the *. Other devices are using this AP no problem

Comment: Does the wireless have an IP address? `ip addr show` Are there any clues here? `dmesg | grep wlp` I will be off for the rest of the evening. I'll check back tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try a driver parameter. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options cfg80211 cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=Y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf
exit
```

Reboot. If there is no improvement, please make a few changes in the router's setup.

WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

**EDIT**: We note dozens, perhaps hundreds of lines of:

> changed bandwidth, new config

There are many reports of this behavior and it seems always to prohibit the wireless from working at all. Let's try to stop it. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
exit
```

Is there any improvement? If not, there are other parameters that we may try that are increasingly restrictive.

**EDIT 2**: Your device and driver look first for version -50 of the firmware and, not finding it, then -49 and then it finds and loads -48 which is the latest found in the Ubuntu package *linux-firmware.* There is, however, a version -50 available. Let's load it:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Now, let's check to see what version loaded:

```
dmesg | grep firmware
```

Look for later timestamps; the firmware load that occured when the computer first boots will be around 4.00 or so; we are interested in the most recent entries; that is, 50.00 and probably much higher.

Is there any improvement?

Comment: My router mode is already set to 11bgn mixed and moving to use WPA2-PSK with AES encryption did not seem to help. For some more context, I can not even access the settings page of my router while using the wifi connection even though it's a local 192.168.0.1 address

Comment: Can you access the router from another computer on the network and make the 20 MHz change? Any improvement?

Comment: Is the channel in the router fixed, 1,6 or 11, or autoselect?

Comment: hard set to 9. I live in an apartment complex and all those channells are super crowded. 9 Isn't much better but its better

Comment: Fixed is better than autoselect so that's fine. We are trying to stop the wireless from all the bandwidth switching. Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: Well the jumping around stopped, but I still cant get any internet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108201/discussion-between-chili555-and-rosey).