# No Wifi on Ubuntu 20.04 with Intel 9462

Tags: wireless

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my thinkpad x390 but cant get the Wifi to work.

It looks like the system sees the device

```
spci | grep -i net
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V
```

I've installed  backport-iwlwifi-dkms and iwlwifi is loaded

```
 lsmod | grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi               352256  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              778240  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

```
inxi -Nn        
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9462 driver: iwlwifi 
           Device-2: Intel Ethernet I219-V driver: e1000e 
           IF: enp0s31f6 state: down mac: 00:2b:67:10:5d:47 
           Device-3: Realtek RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter type: USB driver: r8152 
           IF: enxa0cec8c81fd9 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: a0:ce:c8:c8:1f:d9
```

I've tried installing the firware in /lib/firmware from intel https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

I cant seem to get the interface to show up

```
iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

enxa0cec8c81fd9  no wireless extensions.
```

What am i missing? I found this post [No internet using Intel Wireless-AC 9462 on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240787/no-internet-using-intel-wireless-ac-9462-on-ubuntu-20-04) but when i go to the Additional Drivers tab i dont have anything show up. I'm guessing a different driver?

Dmesg log

```
dmesg | grep wifi                                  
[    2.980938] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.986441] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.992575] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.992597] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 65.3.35.22
[    2.993072] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.994999] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    3.124726] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x354
[    4.164025] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5623, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    4.164053] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0x8047cb2c
[    4.164086] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x1423a
[    4.164089] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired.
[    4.165326] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode
[    4.165329] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    4.165331] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[    4.165332] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    4.165334] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[    4.165336] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[    4.165337] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[    4.165339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data1
[    4.165340] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
[    4.165342] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[    4.165344] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    4.165345] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[    4.165347] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    4.165349] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    4.165350] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[    4.165352] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[    4.165354] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[    4.165355] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[    4.165357] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hw version
[    4.165358] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | board version
[    4.165360] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[    4.165362] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr0
[    4.165363] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    4.165365] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr2
[    4.165366] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr3
[    4.165368] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    4.165370] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    4.165371] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[    4.165373] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    4.165375] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[    4.165376] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    4.165378] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    4.165380] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    4.165381] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    4.165383] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[    4.165568] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    4.165570] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    4.165573] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[    4.165575] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    4.165577] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80461F16 | umac branchlink2
[    4.165579] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8047CB2C | umac interruptlink1
[    4.165581] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8047CB2C | umac interruptlink2
[    4.165583] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[    4.165585] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8047CB2C | umac data2
[    4.165587] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[    4.165589] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000037 | umac major
[    4.165591] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD9698065 | umac minor
[    4.165594] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000FA7BF | frame pointer
[    4.165596] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886270 | stack pointer
[    4.165598] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    4.165600] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    4.165655] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    4.165660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    4.165686] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80260000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    4.165690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    4.165718] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    4.165722] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0794B750 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    4.165748] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    4.165752] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    4.165780] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    4.165784] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.165813] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.165820] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    4.165881] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    4.165907] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    4.613763] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Answer (score 0):

Firmware issue.

I needed `iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-56.ucode` in `/lib/firmware`

Comment: Good job solving it. Where did you get the file from? Can you expand on this to make it more helpful to others who might have the same issue?